# OS X - handle user exceptions in kernel

Tags: c, macos, exception, kernel

I know I can handle in my own program, any exception using the mach port exception mechanism or by using signal handlers.
Is there any way to receive those exception / signals (that my user mode program has created) in my kernel mode driver somehow?

will it involve any kind of hooking?

or is there any api for it?

Thanks

Comment: Doing things in the kernel generally requires a kernel extension, so you can seek more information on that. However, there is no reason to use a kernel extension merely to handle signals for your own process. And installing a kernel extension to handle exceptions or signals for other processes is generally a bad idea and is probably not the right solution for the real problem you are trying to solve. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to catch signals for any user mode process using my kernel extension. just as a PoC and nothing more.